# Make decision tree as weak learner, but it get > 80% score

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree, adaboost

I am using sklearn AdaBoostClassfier and DecisonTreeClassfier to test Abalone Dataset which is in UCI repository. I just check the performance of DecisonTreeClassfier with max_depth is 1, I found it is always > 80%, how can I use such a tree as a weak learner?

For decision tree, I use max_depth = 1 and splitter = 'random', from the doc, 'random' means random best, so it is not randomly picking any feature to split.

How should I handle such case? thanks.

Comment: You might achieve 80% accuracy because your dataset is imbalanced, have you checked that?

Comment: @MaximeKan thanks. You are right, the data are very skewed. Actually the predicted values are # of rings, which are integer, to make it classification question, I categorize them to young, adult and old based on different ring numbers. The criterion I gave for adult class is too wide so it takes the major part of all samples. I will try to relabel them.
Another thing, the weak learner means any learn better than a random one. So the "strong" learner here is OK I guess.